# compare one rows to another rows to popup message for duplicates and restrict move to next line if duplicates are still present

Tags: excel, vba

this code is not working  as expected,it should compare like ( 1st row compared to 2nd , 1st to 3rd and so on if any duplicates value are there than it should restrict to move next line)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Columns("A:F")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            If Target.Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value Or _
                Target.Value = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

                    MsgBox "Duplicate when introduced " & Target.Value & " in " & Target.Address
                    Debug.Print Target.Address

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're looking for duplicates, just use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` on `Target.Column`.

Comment: @BigBen-could u please post the code

Comment: i have to compare two entire rows